# Getting Errors While Compling Multiple C++ Files

Tags: c++, compilation, visual-studio-code, linker-errors

I am getting linker errors. I changed the args["-g"] from ${file} to "${workspaceFolder}\**.cpp" this in tasks.json. I added the build command in the terminal below , how can I make vscode compile all the files in the same workspace.Also I tried manualy making the .exe's but when I tried to debug the code I get the error that main.exe does not exists.

**launch.json**

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "g++.exe - Etkin dosyayı derle ve dosyada hata ayıkla",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "gdb için düzgün yazdırmayı etkinleştir",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe etkin dosyayı derle"
    }
  ]
}
```

**task.json**

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
      "command": "C:\\MinGW64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "Hata Ayıklayıcısı tarafından oluşturulan görev."
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "account.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Account erol_account;
    erol_account.set_name("Erol's Account");
    erol_account.set_balance(1000.0);

    if (erol_account.deposit(200.0))
    {
        cout << "Deposit OK\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Deposit Not Allowed\n";
    }

    if (erol_account.withdraw(500.0))
    {
        cout << "Withdrawal OK\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No Sufficent Funds\n";
    }

    if (erol_account.withdraw(1500.0))
    {
        cout << "Withdrawal OK\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No Sufficent Funds\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**account.cpp**

```
#include "account.hpp"

void Account::set_name(std::string n)
{
    name = n;
}
std::string Account::get_name()
{
    return name;
}
bool Account::deposit(double amount)
{
    // If very amount
    balance += amount;
    return true;
}

bool Account::withdraw(double amount)
{
    if (balance - amount >= 0)
    {
        balance -= amount;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**account.hpp**

```
#ifndef _ACCOUNT_H_
#define _ACCOUNT_H_
#include <string>
#pragma once

class Account
{
private:
    // Attributes

    std::string name;
    double balance;

public:
    // Methods
    // Declared Inline
    void set_balance(double bal) { balance = bal; }
    double get_balance() { return balance; }

    // Methods will declared outside the class decleration
    void set_name(std::string n);
    std::string get_name();

    bool deposit(double amount);
    bool withdraw(double amount);
};

#endif
```

**error message**

```
PS D:\VsCode\Udemy C++\Section 13-OOP\Implementing Member Methods\Second Method> cd "d:\VsCode\Udemy C++\Section 13-OOP\Implementing Member Methods\Second Method\" ; if ($?) { g++ main.cpp -o main } 
; if ($?) { .\main }
C:\Users\EROLEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccimuw0z.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `Account::set_name(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
C:\Users\EROLEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccimuw0z.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `Account::deposit(double)'
C:\Users\EROLEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccimuw0z.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `Account::withdraw(double)'
C:\Users\EROLEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccimuw0z.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `Account::withdraw(double)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS D:\VsCode\Udemy C++\Section 13-OOP\Implementing Member Methods\Second Method>
```

**debug error**
[debug error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LROxk.png)

Comment: Why is your header double guarded?

Comment: The pre-launch task is `"C/C++: g++.exe etkin dosyayı derle"` but you've shown us a different task `"C/C++: g++.exe build active file"`.

Comment: `if ($?) { g++ main.cpp -o main } ` shows its only compiling main.cpp

Comment: The pre-launch task being different may be the issue.

Comment: @drescherjm how can i fix it ?Should change the label, preLaunchTask  and name to the same thing? I know i asked too many questions and I am still getting arround vscode's thıngs.